# Get value from nested class using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public class CustomProperty<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public CustomProperty(T val)
    {
        _value = val;
    }
    public T Value
    {
        get { return this._value; }
        set { this._value = value; }
    }
}

public class CustomPropertyAccess
{
    public CustomProperty<string> Name = new CustomProperty<string>("cfgf");
    public CustomProperty<int> Age = new CustomProperty<int>(0);
    public CustomPropertyAccess() { }
}

//I jest beginer in reflection. 

//How can access GetValue of  CPA.Age.Value using fuly reflection


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CustomPropertyAccess CPA = new CustomPropertyAccess();
   CPA.Name.Value = "lino";
   CPA.Age.Value = 25;

//I did like this . this is the error   “ Non-static method requires a target.”
MessageBox.Show(CPA.GetType().GetField("Name").FieldType.GetProperty("Value").GetValue(null     ,null).ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a method like this:

```
public Object GetPropValue(String name, Object obj) {
    foreach (String part in name.Split('.')) {
        if (obj == null) { return null; }

        Type type = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(part);
        if (info == null) { return null; }

        obj = info.GetValue(obj, null);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And use it like so:

```
Object val = GetPropValue("Age.Value", CPA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message.

Non-static methods and properties are associated with an instance of a class - and so you need to provide an instance when trying to access them through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

In the `GetProperty.GetValue` method, you need to specify the object for which you want to get the property value. In your case, it would be: `GetValue(CPA ,null)`